# What happens when running a piston pump below minimum air drive?

Tags: pressure, pumps

My question is what happens when you give an air driven liquid piston pump less air drive pressure then the minimum recommended. I have a pump that says its minimum drive pressure is 25psi. What would happen when I send the pump air pressure less than this amount and try to hold it at 10psi. Would the outlet pressure still be the ratio of the pump? I imagine it would build pressure, but it would not be able to hold it because it can't cycle (unless you give it constant air pressure?), also the pump would try to cycle but can't, right?

I am asking this because I have 2 of the exact same model pumps one of which is 3 years older than the other, the nominal ratio is 14:1 and the actual ratio is 16:1. The older one of them can produce minimum outlet pressures of around 110psi because our fluid supply is 80psi and can cycle at less than 10psi air pressure. The other newer pump is the one I am trying to use and when I give it less than 10psi air pressure the pump never cycles but still builds outlet pressure, when I am trying to hold the pressure, the pump tries to cycle but cannot because of lack of air pressure. When the pump tries to cycle, I think it causes a pressure wave/spike in the outlet side because the gauge shoots up 100psi for a second before returning down.

I am not sure what is happening because the pumps are the same models and should have the same specs but for some reason the newer pump cannot cycle at less than 10psi air drive pressure. Either there was a design change or the pump got serviced.

Comment: The older pump is worn and has less internal friction.

Comment: I asked some coworkers and they said whenever they first got the pump, they were doing 150psi tests meaning that the air drive was less than 10psi. I am so confused now because I have the exact same pump, but it can't do the same process. Btw, I am controlling the pump using an IP transducer (current to pneumatic) which is the same thing as a regulator right?